# Numpy: proper way of getting maximum from a list of points

Tags: python, numpy, max

I have a list of points in 3d coordinates system (X, Y, Z). Moreover, each of them have assigned a float value *v*, so a single point might be described as (*x*, *y*, *z*, *v*). This list is represented as a numpy array of *shape=(N,4)*. For each 2d position *x*, *y* I need to get the maximum value of *v*. A straightforward but computationally expensive way would be:

```
for index in range(points.shape[0]):
    x = points[index, 0]
    y = points[index, 1]
    v = points[index, 3]

    maxes[x, y] = np.max(maxes[x, y], v)
```

Is there a more "numpy" approach, which would be able to bring some gain in terms of performance?

Comment: Why is `np.max(points[:, 3])` not sufficient?

Comment: @CedricH. They want to know the max *for each `x, y` pair.* Basically groupby `x, y` and find the max for each group

Comment: @SVengat yeap, however I wonder if numpy would be able to vectorize this in someway.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Thanks, I missed that.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your list? Are they actually tuples? Or just arrays

Comment: @user3483203 it's a numpy array of shape [N, 4] as mentioned in the problem description. I wrote "tuples" but didn't really mean a tuple in terms of python. Sorry, if it was not clear enough.

Comment: Do coordinates x, y, and z follow any kind of structure, i.e. do they represent consecutive coordinates in a 3D grid? If not, are they integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Setup***

```
points = np.array([[ 0,  0,  1,  1],
                   [ 0,  0,  2,  2],
                   [ 1,  0,  3,  0],
                   [ 1,  0,  4,  1],
                   [ 0,  1,  5, 10]])
```

---

The general idea here is sorting using the first, second, and fourth columns, and reversing that result, so that when we find our unique values, the value with the maximum value in the fourth column will be above other values with similar x and y coordinates.  Then we use `np.unique` to find the unique values in the first and second columns, and return those results, which will have the maximum `v`:

#### Using `lexsort` and `numpy.unique`

```
def max_xy(a):
    res = a[np.lexsort([a[:, 3], a[:, 1], a[:, 0]])[::-1]]
    vals, idx = np.unique(res[:, :2], 1, axis=0)
    maximums = res[idx]
    return maximums[:, [0,1,3]]
```

```
array([[ 0,  0,  2],
       [ 0,  1, 10],
       [ 1,  0,  1]])
```

---

#### Avoiding `unique` for better performance

```
def max_xy_v2(a):
    res = a[np.lexsort([a[:, 3], a[:, 1], a[:, 0]])[::-1]]
    res = res[np.append([True], np.any(np.diff(res[:, :2],axis=0),1))]
    return res[:, [0,1,3]]

max_xy_v2(points)
```

```
array([[ 1,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  1, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  2]])
```

Notice that while both will return correct results, they will not be sorted as the original lists were, you can simply add another `lexsort` at the end to fix this if you like.

Comment: Thhe second solution is great!! Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, not a purely "numpy" solution either, but [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package provides a very convenient (and fast) way to do this.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(points[:, 0:2]).max(points[:,3])
```

### Comparison to Other Methods

```
%timeit npi.group_by(points[:, 0:2]).max(points[:,3])
58 µs ± 435 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


%timeit pd.DataFrame(points, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'V']).groupby(by=['X', 'Y']).apply(lambda r: r['V'].max()).reset_index().values
3.15 ms ± 36.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

def max_xy_ver1(a):
    res = a[np.lexsort([a[:, 0], a[:, 1], a[:, 3]])[::-1]]
    vals, idx = np.unique(res[:, :2], 1, axis=0)
    maximums = res[idx]
    return maximums[:, [0,1,3]]

%timeit max_xy_ver1(points)
63.5 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

def max_xy_ver2(a):
    res = a[np.lexsort([a[:, 3], a[:, 1], a[:, 0]])[::-1]]
    res = res[np.append([True], np.any(np.diff(res[:, :2],axis=0),1))]
    return res[:, [0,1,3]]

%timeit_max_xy_ver2(points) # current winner
31.7 µs ± 524 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

def findmaxes_simple(points):
    maxes = {}
    for index in range(points.shape[0]):
        x = points[index, 0]
        y = points[index, 1]
        v = points[index, 3]
        maxes[(x, y)] = v if (x,y) not in maxes else max(maxes[(x, y)],v)
    return maxes

%timeit findmaxes_simple(points)
82.6 µs ± 632 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

### Installing numpy_indexed via Pip

pip install --user numpy_indexed

(If you are on Ubuntu and some other Linux distros, you may have to use `pip3` to install the package for python 3)

### Data Used for Tests

Pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/NVu2jEaV).

Comment: Mind adding the timings for my updated solution? Should be considerably faster

Comment: @user3483203 sure thing, 1 sec :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not pure `numpy` and I take advantage of `pandas` which I believe will do its best to vectorize:

```
a = [
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 2, 2],
    [1, 0, 3, 0],
    [1, 0, 4, 1],
    [0, 1, 5, 10],
]
pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'V']).groupby(by=['X', 'Y']).apply(lambda r: r['V'].max()).reset_index().values
```

Returning this:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  2],
       [ 0,  1, 10],
       [ 1,  0,  1]])
```

Comment: Here is a vectorized version of this answer: `pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'V']).groupby(by=['X', 'Y']).V.max().reset_index().values`

Answer (score 0):

In pure numpy :

```
import numpy as np

points = np.array([(1,2,3,4),
                   (2,3,5,6),
                   (1,2,9,8)])  #an example,

def find_vmax(x, y) :
    xpoints = points[np.where( points[:,0] == x)[0]]
    xypoints = xpoints[np.where( xpoints[:,1] == y)[0]]
    return np.max(xypoints[:, 3])

print(find_vmax(1, 2))
```

Comment: This provides only the result for a single (x,y) combination. You would have to use np.unique to get all of them and iterate through all of them in a standard for loop to get the complete solution.